# Question about solving Newton's laws' problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

A questions from my textbook asks me what the force by the pulley on the roof is.

[image]

In order to answer the question, need I consider those objects hanging from both sides of the rope, or need I only consider the tension in the rope (assuming I already have the tension).

If the tension in the rope is $T$, then the force by the pulley on the roof is $2*T$, because there are two ropes with tension $T$ pulling down on the roof.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Hi Josh and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about this question is that you can essentially ignore the tension and the pulley. You only need to look at the total gravitational force of everything hanging from the pulley to figure out the force on the roof (assuming the situation is static).

Your reasoning with the tension is correct, that the force on the roof is $2T$. Don't make the mistake of assuming the tension is equal to the gravitational force of the hanging mass though.